# Should I write "written on" or "written on it" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> Mary stood before me, draped with my blanket like a nun and holding a
>   napkin that had written on (it), *You don't want to play with me
>   anymore?*

Should I write *written on* or *written on it*? I'm confused because I see both [occurrences](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22napkin%20that%20had%20written%22&rlz=1C1ASUC_enTW628TW628&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGhZ_U6ePYAhWEw7wKHXyPBU8Q_AUICSgA&biw=1920&bih=925&dpr=1) on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I follow the occurrences link in your question, I see three quotes, and all of them contain **it**.

The word order in your sentence is unusual, and maybe that's what is confusing you. Here is the sentence with a more conventional word order, and the actual text replaced by "something". When it is written like this, it should be clear that **it** is necessary.

> Mary stood before me, draped in my blanket like a nun and holding a napkin that had **something** written on it.

The word order in your sentence is also valid when writing in a literary style:

> Mary stood before me, draped in my blanket like a nun and holding a napkin that had written on it "You don't want to play with me any more?"

Note that I have replaced **draped with** by **draped in**. The reason is that **draped with** is used to describe some sort of decoration, for example,

> The Christmas tree was draped with tinsel

**draped in** can also be used for this, but is usually used when a person has something wrapped round them and is effectively wearing it.

> It flaunted a digitally modified photograph of five men—West Bengal Chief Minister Buddhadeb Bhattacharjee and his top four administrators—draped in colorful saris. [Pluralism and Democracy in India: Debating the Hindu Right](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=Dh1cBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT125&dq=%22draped%20in%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjspIPq7uPYAhVBM48KHRKrBKsQ6AEITTAI#v=onepage&q=%22draped%20in%22&f=false)

For a blanket, **draped in** is the more appropriate term.

Comment: +1 I wonder if your illustration could be made even more clear with a step after "that had something written on it" stating that is can also be phrased *that had written on it[,] something.* It's obvious to me that's what you're saying but I thing showing it explicitly might better guide some ELs?

Answer (score 2):

Of those two choices, only *that had written on it* is grammatical.

Something that uses *on which had been written . . .* is another choice, and some people will this is correct while the other way is not. However both are grammatical with this one being quite formal.

I assume that you don't know--or don't want readers to know--who wrote it. If we do know, then a more simple style might be easier to read, for example: *on which she had written.* You might also consider *napkin, on which had written,* xxxxxxx.

Comment: I'm curious about "napkin, on which had written, xxxxxx". Does it omit the subject **she** in this case?

Comment: @dan Good question. It is a curious structure, and I don't know exactly how to describe it, but no: What I had in mind does not suppose that we know who did the writing. So, it's somewhat similar to the idea in: *There was a sign which read, "Abandon hope, all ye who enter here."

Now that you called my attention to it, I can't feel sure it's standard English or odd, or maybe both! Consider: "Mary Jones clawed her way though the bushes in the moonless sky in the overgrown cemetery. Much to her horror, there appeared a tombstone on which had written, *Mary Jones - Died now.*

Comment: The grammar is more clear in something like *She held a napkin, on which had written the words, *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ....*